# What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus

> What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{-x^2}$?

I am calculating $\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx$. By integration by parts, I have
$$I = -\frac{1}{2}xe^{-x^2} |_{0}^\infty+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$$

The second integration is just $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. Now I want to know how to calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} xe^{-x^2}$. It is in the form of $\infty \cdot 0$.

Comment: Maybe writing it as $x/e^{x^2}$ will make it more clear

Comment: Whenever you have a limit of the form $\infty \cdot 0$ you can take the reciprocal of one of the terms and put it in the denominator to get a limit of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By L'Hôpital's
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2xe^{x^2}}=0
$$
note: the above will evaluate to 0 for any expression of the form
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^{x}}
$$
where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: sad! $\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Note that for all $x \geqslant 0$

$$e^{x^2} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{1!}+ \frac{x^4}{2!} + \ldots > x^2\\ \implies 0 \leqslant  x e^{- x^2}< \frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x}.$$

The squeeze theorem shows the limit is $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For the limit itself, it's useful to remember that exponentials will *always* win out over polynomials. Even for something absurd like:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{100,000}e^{-x} = 0$$

Based off of the nature of your question, I'm guessing you are currently in an introductory calculus course. You'll later see that you can express:

$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$

which I think makes it a bit easier to see why exponentials always dominate polynomials.

As for the direct calculation of the integral, there's a neat trick that might come in handy someday. Consider instead the integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx$

This can be rewritten as:

$-\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx$

The integral is a standard Gaussian now, so if we remember that:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}$

Thus,

$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx = -\frac{d}{da}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}} = \frac{\pi}{4a^{3/2}}$

and setting $a = 1$ as we have in our problem yields the answer $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$.

Comment: No, I absolutely misunderstood the crux of his question at first (focusing on the integral rather than the step he was on, which was my fault). I've edited my answer some to reflect that.

Comment: no worries, I will delete my above